# Bibliography not working in Mac after compiling in Linux

Tags: editors, cross-platform

I am working on a paper with my teacher. He works on mac and me on Fedora. He uses TexShop or TexPad, and I use TexStudio.

We have always had issues, sometimes it would take him a few tries for his references to show up after I had compiled it but it always went to normal. The error in TexShop is about ISO and doesnt compile anything, just error (it says it should be UTF-8 when it is already like that and mine also compiles with that encoding). TexPad shows the text with no references, even after deleting the auxiliary files and trying again the references are not shown. No error is displayed in TexPad. My compilations were always smooth, no errors and the references showing right away.

He hadnt been able to show the references for a week now so we had to come up with a solution. He downloaded TexMaker. which is a cross-platform well known editor that he gogoled, and now it works for him. No errors and the references show. What could be causing this problem? Thanks!

Edit: We would prefer to find a way to make TexPad or TexShop work since the rest of the authors are also in mac (I am the only one in linux) and we cant ask for all of them to install another program.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! There is not much difference between mac and linux. Encode your tex files in `utf8 ` and then you should be able to compile them with both systems.

Comment: They are encoded like that

Comment: It would be helpful to know more about the error you got. (If there is no bibliography, there should definitely be at least a warning in the `.log`. Check the `.log` file directly, not the warnings/errors displayed by the editor.) Can you reproduce the exact error message here? It would also help if you could provide code that lets us reproduce your problem. At the moment your question is quite vague. If the files were encoded correctly, did you check that all editors involved actually expected UTF8 files?

Comment: if you are using a separate `.bib` file for reference database, check the encoding of that file also, and check if the file contains special characters. you may also try copying the `bbl` file after compile and paste it into the tex file to make it standalone.

Comment: I don't really have a  minimal example to show, it works on my computer so there is nothing wrong with text itself, is the compilers that are different between computers and not compatible somehow.  Can't check the error message at the moment because I am not with my teacher. We do work with a separate `.bib` file which is also encoded as utf-8 (checked on terminal). I did not know about the `bbl` file, will definetly think about doing that when it's time to send it to the rest of the authors. Thanks!. PS: The files are shared through a dropbox folder, so we both have the exact same ones.

Comment: Can you check that the versions of BibTeX and `pdflatex` (or whatever engine you use to compile) are in fact the same on both machines?

Comment: The problem persisted and we found no solution but to use texmaker at that moment. Because of several problems with my OS I am now in another linux system, Ubuntu, used to have Fedora, and we havent tried to see how it is at the moment. Do you have the same problem?